# Why does The Experimenter wear goggles?

Tags: la-jetee

A man known as "The Head Experimenter" can be seen wearing strange -telescope like- black goggles in numerous photographs from Chris Marker's *La Jetée* (1962). He is the chief of a group of scientists (and torturers) who conduct experiments on prisoners.

Goggles are typically worn to protect the eyes from external agents such as flying objects, extreme light, and so on, or to see better under water or in bright sunlight. Nowadays, goggles provide a technological role (called augmented reality) in warfare by showing data, but a simple reason to wear goggles may be required prescription. The case is that the aforementioned individual is the only one among his fellow scientists, working in time travel experiments in an underground prison camp beneath a post apocalypse Paris, who is wearing those unusual goggles.

I inquire whether there is a canon reason for why the experimenter wears goggles.

[image: Image from the film La Jetée (1962) by Chris Marker]

For a better detail, here a picture of actor Jacques Ledoux wearing the goggles that he used in the film.

[image: photo of Jacques Ledoux wearing film goggles]

Comment: Those look more like binocular magnifiers than goggles (https://i.etsystatic.com/34656542/r/il/18cfe1/4355055778/il_fullxfull.4355055778_calb.jpg)

Comment: @DavidW - Very intriguing, however normally magnifiers are used to observe items in detail, such as those used by watchmakers and jewelers, but the character in the film uses them more like spectacles.

Comment: I used to have a friend in school who had actual telescopic lenses mounted to a frame to compensate for a degenerative eye disease. The thing in the movie is certainly a magnifier worn for the cool looks, but in real life huge lenses are not unheard of (e.g. https://ialvs.com/ways-we-can-help/resources-for-eye-care-professionals/telescope-glasses-for-low-vision-when-why-how-and-more/, scroll down a bit for pictures.